# R Project: Plot a 3d Mesh (grid) using Plot3D package

Tags: r, plot3d

I'm trying to plot a 3d grid with cuboid elements (transparent using the Plot3D package of R, however I cannot find a good solution. Any suggestions? The objective is to add the 3D grid in a 3d scatterplot using the function scatter3D.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What are the coding problems you are experiencing?  Please make your question reproducible [MRE]: include a sample of your data into the question using `dput(your_dataframe)` [Helpful guidance for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just work out the ends of the line segments in your plot.  There are three kinds of them, depending on which axis they are parallel to.   I think you'll need to add NA points betwen each pair if you want to use `scatter3D`; if you were using `rgl` instead, you could use `segments3d`.

Comment: Oops, just noticed `plot3D::segments3D`.  So you could use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code which solves my problem. I used the function 'lines3D' of the Plot3D package. I'll appreciate it if you can provide a more elegant way to avoid the loops.

```
library(plot3D)
library(plot3Drgl)
x_grid <- y_grid  <- seq(0 , 1000, 200)
z_grid<-seq(0 , 500, 100)
# plot a 3-D mesh

M <- mesh(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid)
# plot result

dev.new()
scatter3D(M$x, M$y, M$z, pch = "-", cex = 0.1, colkey = FALSE,ticktype = "detailed")

for(i in 1:length(z_grid)){
for(j in 1:length(y_grid)){
lines3D(x = c(min(x_grid), max(x_grid)), y = c(y_grid[j],y_grid[j]), z = c(z_grid[i],z_grid[i]),colkey = FALSE,add=TRUE)}}

for(i in 1:length(x_grid)){
for(j in 1:length(y_grid)){
lines3D(x = c(x_grid[i],x_grid[i]), y = c(y_grid[j],y_grid[j]), z = c(min(z_grid), max(z_grid)),colkey = FALSE,add=TRUE)}}

for(i in 1:length(x_grid)){
for(j in 1:length(z_grid)){
lines3D(x = c(x_grid[i],x_grid[i]), y = c(min(y_grid), max(y_grid)), z = c(z_grid[j],z_grid[j]),colkey = FALSE,add=TRUE)}}

plotrgl(new = TRUE)
```

[image]